# Express/Solve formula with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, formulas

I am trying to create a fairly simply form that will allow variables to be inputted and a given formula solved.  I am stumbling on how to express the formula and how to make the first two variables understood as an exponent.

Here is the complete formula that works in Excel (cell labels replaced with input names for html):

```
=varNk * varQr * ( 273 + varT ) / ( 273 + varTo ) * varPp / varP * varKq * varKak
```

Note that "varNk" and "varQr" are values entered with exponents - i.e. 97.53^12

EDIT: Actual formula (link to image as I don't have enough rep to post directly)- http://mattk.net/DwFormula1.PNG

Here is what I attempted to make work.  I wasn't sure the correct way to assemble the final output, but ideally I want to figure out how to make it a single button operation.

```
<head>
   <script>
      function doCalcOne()
      {
      var varNk = document.getElementById('varNk').value;    
      var varQr = document.getElementById('varQr').value;   
      var varT = document.getElementById('varT').value;
      var varTo = document.getElementById('varTo').value;
      var varPo = document.getElementById('varPo').value;
      var varP = document.getElementById('varP').value;
      var varKq = document.getElementById('varKq').value;
      var varKak = document.getElementById('varKak').value;

      var result1 = document.getElementById('stepOne');
      var stepOne = varNk * varQr;
      result1.value = stepOne;

      }
      function doCalcTwo()
      {
      var result2 = document.getElementById('stepTwo');
      var stepTwo = parseInt(varT.value) + 273;
      result2.value = stepTwo;
      }
   </script>
</head>
<html>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Step One:<input id="stepOne" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Step Two:<input id="stepTwo" /></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <div id="DoseRateCalc">
      <p>Enter the values below to calculate the Dose Rate</p>
   </div>
   <table style="width:600px;border:1px solid #000;">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p>Nk=<input id="varNk" type="text"></p>
         </td>
         <td>
            <p>TN 34013 IC Cal Certificate Detection Calibration Factor</p>
         </td>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p>Qr=<input id="varQr" type="text"></p>
         </td>
         <td>
            <p>Unidos measured charge in pC (pico coulumb)@20mm</p>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p>T=<input id="varT" type="text"></p>
         </td>
         <td>
            <P>Current temperature</p>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p>To=<input id="varTo" type="text"></p>
         </td>
         <td>
            <p>TN34013 IC cal certificate protocol temp</p>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p>Po=<input id="varPo" type="text"></p>
         </td>
         <td>
            <p>Current pressure</p>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p>P=<input id="varP" type="text"></p>
         </td>
         <td>
            <p>TN34013 IC cal certificate protocol pressure</p>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p>Kq=<input id="varKq" type="text"></p>
         </td>
         <td>
            <p>TN34013 IC cal certificate protocol TW30 Beam Quality Correction value</p>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p>Kak->DW=<input id="varKak" type="text">
         </td>
         <td>
            <p>Correction factor TN 34013 IC  from PTW. Air Kerma --> absorbed dose to water convertion for TW30 Water Phantom Manual pg43</p>
         </td>
      </tr>
      </p>
      <p><input type="button" value="Calculate Step 1" onClick="doCalcOne()"></p>
      <p><input type="button" value="Calculate Step 2" onClick="doCalcTwo()"></p>
   </table>
   <br>    
</html>
```

EDIT 2: 
Working function:

```
    function doCalcOne()
{
    var varNk = document.getElementById('varNk').value;    
    var varQr = document.getElementById('varQr').value;   
    var varT = document.getElementById('varT').value;
    var varTo = document.getElementById('varTo').value;
    var varPo = document.getElementById('varPo').value;
    var varP = document.getElementById('varP').value;
    var varKq = document.getElementById('varKq').value;
    var varKak = document.getElementById('varKak').value;

    var result1 = document.getElementById('stepOne');
    var stepOne = varNk * (Math.pow(10,9)) * varQr * (Math.pow(10,-12)) * ( 273 + varT ) / ( 273 + varTo ) * varPo / varP * varKq * varKak;

    num = stepOne;
    result1.value = num.toPrecision(4);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `doCalcTwo` function at the end of `doCalcOne`, passing along any variables you need, and you should get what you expect! You can nuke the 2nd button you have as well. Here's the updated code:

**Update:** I made it all one function and added what I think is the correct math. I don't have a clue what you're actually trying to calculate but Excel-style math can translate over to JavaScript almost one-to-one. The order of operations is up to you!

```
function doCalcOne()
{
    var varNk = document.getElementById('varNk').value;    
    var varQr = document.getElementById('varQr').value;   
    var varT = document.getElementById('varT').value;
    var varTo = document.getElementById('varTo').value;
    var varPo = document.getElementById('varPo').value;
    var varP = document.getElementById('varP').value;
    var varKq = document.getElementById('varKq').value;
    var varKak = document.getElementById('varKak').value;

    var result1 = document.getElementById('stepOne');
    var stepOne = varNk * varQr * ( 273 + varT ) / ( 273 + varTo ) * varPp / varP * varKq * varKak;

    result1.value = stepOne;
}
```

Honestly, you don't need two functions here but I assume you have/had your reasons to break it up like that. Just know that you can definitely combine these functions into one and it should work.

Another point I'd like to make is that the variables you create inside one function will not be available to different function. This is called "scope" and its easily determined by looking at opening/closing curly brackets (`{ and }`). Poorly formatted code makes this much harder to keep track of ;).

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate your fast response and time to sort through this mess!  I am still a little lost as to how I can create this all under one function? With my final value needing to represent 
    '=varNk * varQr * ( 273 + varT ) / ( 273 + varTo ) * varPp / varP * varKq * varKak'    

 and how to make the first two variables accept the format of  23^12 (purely an example).  I am sorry for not understanding this right away.

Comment: No problem, and to do exponents in JavaScript you use the [pow](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pow.asp) function. If you need to take the base and the exponent as variables, you'll either have to parse the text "23^12" (difficult, but not really that hard) or just provide two input boxes, one for the base and one for the exponent.

Comment: Also, I think the math was wrong originally, and that was your question! I'll update my answer!

Comment: Ahh, I think I am starting to understand!  Also, the two numbers that are needed to be entered with an exponent, the exponent is constant.  Nk = x^9 (or x*10[9]) and Qr = y^-12 (or y*10[-12]).  I am trying to write it as:
    var a = Math.pow(varNk, 9);
    var b = Math.pow(varQr, -12);

Then change the formula to - 
    a * b * ( 273 + varT ) / ( 273 + varTo ) * varPo / varP * varKq * varKak;

Comment: Thanks to your guidance I was able to get this working.  I successfully calculated the exponent for each variable and restricted the output to 4 decimal places.  The math is correct, now I can use this as a guide for the remaining steps for my calculations.  Thanks again!!!!